# maximum memory allocation in C++Builder 6

Tags: c++, malloc, c++builder-6

I am writing an application in C++Builder 6 Enterprise.

The maximum memory the software allows me to reserve is around 870 MB, no more. The physical memory available on the system is 8 GB and the PC is running Windows 7.

Immediately after a memory allocation statement like `malloc(870000000)` is executed, Task Manager says the memory used by the whole system is 2.5 GB.

My question is, why can't I allocate up to end of available memory?

Comment: Is this a 32-bit application?

Comment: @NeilButterworth yes, C++Builder 6 can only produce 32bit apps

Answer (score 2):

C++Builder 6 was released in 2002, and can produce only 32bit apps. The ability to produce 64bit apps was added in C++Builder XE3 in 2012.

A 32bit app cannot access more than 4GB max, no matter what.

Apps written in C++Builder 6 are not Large Address Aware (and it is not safe to manually mark them as such, as the RTL and memory manager are not LAA compatible), so the most memory they can hope to access is 2GB max (the other 2GB is reserved for Windows to use).

When you ask `malloc()` to allocate ~830 MB (not 870 MB, which would be `912261120` instead of `870000000`), you are asking it to allocate 1 *contiguous* block of memory, which is likely to fail in a non-trivial app.

Even if the app were Large Address Aware, that would up the accessible memory to only 3GB on 32bit Windows (only if the `/3GB` flag is enabled on Windows startup), and 4GB on 64bit Windows.

So, you will never be able to get a 32bit app to allocate anywhere close to the full 8GB. You need a 64bit app for that.